# SystemC undefined Symbol for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, xcode, c++14, c++17, systemc

I'm trying to run SystemC on XCode on mac (using the standard Clang compiler). Depending on the language dialect, I get different error messages. If I use C++14, I get the error

`No member named 'experimental' in namespace 'std'`

If I use the standard c++17, I get the error message

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "sc_core::sc_api_version_2_3_3_cxx201402L<&(sc_core::SC_DISABLE_VIRTUAL_BIND_UNDEFINED_)>::sc_api_version_2_3_3_cxx201402L(sc_core::sc_writer_policy)", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

A similar question has been answered, however, the answer was "One of the files didn't have cstdlib included as a header file", without specifying that file. Does anyone know why that error occurs or what the file with the missing header is?

Comment: Seems like you have different `C++` standard compilation flags while building the SystemC library, and the final executable. Can you try and pass the following compiler flag to the compiler: `-std=c++14`? and, update if this helps

Comment: c++14 does not work. It gives me the error `No member named 'experimental' in namespace 'std'`. I don't get this error when I use c++17, but then the error mentioned above happens.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Apple Clang compiler (the one that comes with XCode)

Comment: Can you update this info along with the compiler version in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SystemC, the *kernel* and the *model* need to be compiled with the same set of modern C++ features enabled, see the `RELEASENOTES` and `INSTALL` files in the package. By default, the currently selected C++ standard of the compiler is used by SystemC (i.e. from `-std=c++17`).

To build SystemC for use across different C++ standard settings, explicitly define the preprocessor flag `SC_CPLUSPLUS` to the *minimum* version you need when building both, the kernel *and* your models.

For example

- build SystemC with `-std=c++11` (aka `SC_CPLUSPLUS=201103L`)
- build your model with a newer C++ standard as you like, but add `-DSC_CPLUSPLUS=201103L` to your compiler flags.

Supported values for `SC_CPLUSPLUS` are:

- 199711L (C++03, ISO/IEC 14882:1998, 14882:2003)
- 201103L (C++11, ISO/IEC 14882:2011)
- 201402L (C++14, ISO/IEC 14882:2014)
- 201703L (C++17, ISO/IEC 14882:2017)

If SystemC 2.3.3 does not work with some version/configuration of the Xcode Clang compiler, you can consider opening an issue at https://github.com/accellera-official/systemc.

Comment: I have never done a lot with c++ and that stuff so I don't know if I read your answer correctly... I have built SystemC using: `../configure --with-arch-suffix= CXXFLAGS='-std=c++11'` and then calling `make install`. Then I went into XCode and added the argument to my compiler flags. Still, does not solve the issue...

Comment: Two questions:  (1)  Did the SystemC installation succeed with these settings? (2) Did you add `-DSC_CPLUSPLUS=201102L` to your compiler flags when building your model?

Comment: (1) I suppose so, There were no errors when building and all the files are there... (2) I hope everything I have to do is add that flag to the section where it says additional Compiler Flags, so I should have done that as well

Comment: My fault, I had a typo in the `SC_CPLUSPLUS` example value, updated post.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the issue. Does that only work if you use the dynamic SystemC library? If I add the static library (libsystemc.a), it gives me an error (library ... .dylib not loaded). If I add the dynamic library, the error obviously vanishes.

Comment: This is independent of shared vs. dynamic linking.